# Confused about internet banking testing

Tags: manual-testing, interview, istqb

I just read a question related to ISTQB (Foundation Level) from a paper which is available in market :

Q - What type of testing will you perform on internet banking solution?

Options :

A. System integration

B. Functional testing

C. Non-functional testing.

D. Requirements testing

And according to them answer is **C. Non-functional testing.**

I agree with the answer , but on the other hand, I am confused that do we not require all other testing for the same application? Please help me to clear this doubt.

Comment: If that is the whole question then I am also confused. Perhaps there is a lot more context given for the question and that needs to be read (or added into this Stackexchange question).

Comment: @AdrianHHH - Yes I know and agree with you but I also got this content only.

Comment: Why do you agree with the 'answer'? Multi choice answers are terrible as they never have an 'it depends' option.

Comment: @PhilKirkham - I agree means non-functional testing require but also need option like 'It depends' Or 'all of above'

Comment: That is a terrible exam question. The wording implies that you should _only_ do _one_ type of testing, which is ridiculous.

Comment: I would contact ISTQB, send them the sqa.stack link and let them answer the question here. http://www.istqb.org/contact-us.html

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal - We should not do that because these online question papers are not approved by ISTQB. I have found question here : http://www.softwaretestinggenius.com/istqb-certification-exam-sample-papers-q-311-to-320

Comment: Ah, I thought it was a real ISTQB exam question, then contact the software testing genius instead ;-)

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal - no. ISTQB never publish exam papers publicly. Their paper are very confidential.

Comment: Yes, this is bit confusing. The question should be clear. But, if you see the choices, only one choice is from Non functional side and all the three have similarities (part of functional testing). So, no choice we have than choosing 'Non functional testing' as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Googling this question gives multiple sites where there are some example questions or mock tests for preparing for ISTQB foundation level certification.

They illustrate well one of the problems in this kind of certification. None of the sites I found explained why this would be the correct answer (or asked for the applicant to explain it, for that matter).

I agree with your opinion that none of the given options is correct in itself, without any further context.

Comment: Yes you are right..I have felt same about those online papers.

Answer (score 1):

Non-functional testing covers below listed testing --

Baseline testing

**Compliance testing**

Documentation testing

Endurance testing

**Load testing**

Localization testing and Internationalization testing

**Performance testing**

**Recovery testing**

Resilience testing

**Security testing**

Scalability testing

Stress testing

**Usability testing**

Volume testing

Question asked for testing of internet banking solution. As per my understanding,  highlighted testing like security, performance, recovery, compliance etc are must to do for internet banking app because 
while accessing banking app on mobile/desktop first point come in mind is security, easy to access(usability), performance of the site.

Comment: Wonder if this answers the question